# list out specific values of a variable for a specific observation

Tags: r

I want to print out the specific dates for a given observation. Below is my data structure.

```
id    date     
1     2017-08-31
1     2017-08-31
1     2017-05-06
2     2015-09-01
2     2015-11-01
3     2010-12-02
3     2010-12-02
```

If I wanted to identify/print the dates for participant 1, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: mydata %>% dplyr::filter(id == 1)

Comment: Or in base R `subset(df, ID == 1)` where `df` is your data frame